# Excel 2007 'Corruption'- Named Ranges vanising, buttons losing Macros

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I'm seeing a lot of weird things happening in some excel sheets I use.

1. Some named ranges vanish
2. Worksheet buttons 'forget' what Macro they should run
3. Named ranges 'forget' what cells they pointed too

Most of the sheets are saved in xlsb

Has anybody else seen behaviour like this or have any idea what causes it??
Dave

Comment: Have you checked for a virus?

Comment: I have update from Office 2003 to 2007 and now I am having this issues as well.

My code creates a new file in Office 2007, then copies a sheet from the 2003 
upgraded file to the new file. So technically the file is new, but the sheet 
had been upgraded from a 2003 file. Without reason and without warning I note 
2 named ranges get removed (there maybe more, but I have only stumbled on 
these 2). The named range is for a single cell and contains a formula.

This happens more often than not when I create the new file, but its always 
the same to named ranges.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! It's a bug in Excel and there is a hot fix here [Excel HotFix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968863/en-us)

Comment: Ouch, lots of stuff in there. Moral of the story, update your MS Office!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that named ranges in macros needs to be adjusted. MS Excel 2003 had this as a sample code

```
Columns("E:E").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Temp2", RefersToR1C1:="='End-2-End'!C6"
```

MS Excel 2007 has this as a sample code.

```
Columns("E:E").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Temp2", RefersToR1C1:="='End-2-End'!C5"
```

This simple change from C6 to C5 is the solution. Once those updates were made in the macros, Named Ranges worked again for me.